# Loop through list of elements and perform a button click

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I'm trying to loop through a list of products and identify a product with discount/promotion. if product with discount is available I want to go inside that product clicking buy now and exist for loop. From what I have tried all the steps are executed but I was not navigated to product details page. Even though the first product doesn't have promotional text if block is executed.

```
 <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 2448px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
   <div class="views-row slick-slide slick-current slick-active" style="width: 286px;" tabindex="0" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
      <article class="commerce-product--phones commerce-product--catalog">
         <div class="no-promotions-block"></div>
         <div class="product-catalog">
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">SAMSUNG GALAXY A5</div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__14 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
               <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-06/phone_Samsung_2.png?itok=4XnjLLPj" width="92" height="100" alt="Alternative_02" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__14 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 0.00</div>
            <div class="list-price">
               Original Price&nbsp;
               <div class="product--variation-field--variation_list_price__14 field field--name-list-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 165,000.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buy-now-button">
               <a href="/product/14" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text" tabindex="0">BUY NOW</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
   </div>
   <div class="views-row slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 286px;" tabindex="0" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false">
      <article class="commerce-product--phones commerce-product--catalog">
         <div class="promotions-block">
            <div class="promotions-text">
               <div class="field field--name-field-offer-tag-line field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Special price 10% OFF</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-catalog">
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Samsung Note 10 - V3</div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__10 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
               <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-04/gsmarena_005.jpg?itok=fgpdOvFL" width="96" height="100" alt="Samsung Galaxy S21 - V3" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__10 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 179,000.00</div>
            <div class="list-price">
               Original Price&nbsp;
               <div class="product--variation-field--variation_list_price__10 field field--name-list-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 179,000.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buy-now-button">
               <a href="/product/10" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text" tabindex="0">BUY NOW</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
   </div>
   <div class="views-row slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 286px;" tabindex="0" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false">
      <article class="commerce-product--phones commerce-product--catalog">
         <div class="promotions-block">
            <div class="promotions-text">
               <div class="field field--name-field-offer-tag-line field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Special promotion 30% OFF</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-catalog">
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">OPPO 60 SE - V4101</div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__1 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
               <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-03/BE2011%201_0.jpg?itok=QOq2qFGz" width="79" height="100" alt="Front view" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__1 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 110,000.00</div>
            <div class="list-price">
               Original Price&nbsp;
               <div class="product--variation-field--variation_list_price__1 field field--name-list-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 110,000.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buy-now-button">
               <a href="/product/8" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text" tabindex="0">BUY NOW</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
   </div>
</div>
```

Code of the page class.

public WithDiscountNavigationPage navigateToDiscountProduct() {

```
//product article
List<WebElement> article = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article[@class='commerce-product--phones commerce-product--catalog']"));

for(WebElement product: article) {
    
    //locate promotional element
    WebElement discountText = product.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='promotions-text']"));

    if(discountText.isDisplayed()) {

        //locate buy now button
        WebElement buyNow = product.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='BUY NOW']"));
        
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", buyNow);
        
        System.out.println("clicked buy now");
        
        break;
                
    }
    
}

        
// return class object
return new WithDiscountNavigationPage();
```

}

I'm not getting any error and test case execution passed.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code worked for me.

```
// product article
List<WebElement> article = driver
        .findElements(By.xpath("//article[@class='commerce-product--phones commerce-product--catalog']"));
for (WebElement product : article) {
    // locate promotional element
    WebElement discountText = product.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='promotions-text']"));
    if (discountText.isDisplayed()) {
        // locate buy now button
        product.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='promotions-text']/parent::div[@class='promotions-block']/following-sibling::div[@class='product-catalog']/div[@class='buy-now-button']/a[text()='BUY NOW']")).click();
        System.out.println("clicked buy now");
        break;
    }
}
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.navigate().back();
```

What I did is,

1. Fetched all products.
2. Then in a for loop checked if the elements have a promotion/discount.
3. First element didn't have a discount, so it was skipped.
4. Second element has discount, so I looked up the parent of the promotion text. then followed to the parent's sibling and then through to the link (Buy Now).
5. I found the link and clicked it. I was redirected to product page for second product.
6. After this the for loop was exited with the `break` statement. So 3 product was not checked.

Answer (score 0):

My observation based on details & code you shared :

- You should NOT use `//locate promotional element` because if promotional discount is available it will work but what if product/article is not having promotional discount?

> WebElement discountText =
> product.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='promotions-text']"));

- Script will keep looking for above `discountText` & it will fail. Even try to avoid `discountText.isDisplayed()`
- Instead you should try

> product.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='promotions-text']")).isEmpty()

- If its empty then neglect and proceed [But it will not get fail while execution]
- If its NOT empty then

> product.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='BUY NOW']")).click()

- Why specifically you are using `JavascriptExecutor` ?
- **Note** : Please check keeping product NOT having promotional discount at the start of the product list and one with promotional discount.
- Understand, I suggested is just a one way of doing/implementing it. There will be other ways to achieve this.

Comment: Using isEmpty() also not worked. Because it returns false for every product article even it should be true.

Comment: I see. This means we need to change the identified element. We are using incorrect element.

Comment: @DarshaniKaushalya Is it working now for you? Highly appreciate if you respond quickly

Comment: No there is no other element to identify whether product has discount. I'm still trying to find a way

Comment: I see. Do not think of directly changing element. You can try to change locator may be it will work

Comment: @DarshaniKaushalya Suggestion : When you use stack overflow platform do accept the answer. Do not hesitate. This might help person who all are going to refer you question in future too. Thanks